# Wrapping an inner 'div' tightly by an outer 'div'

Tags: html, css

```css
#main .thumbBorder {
    background-color: #e1e1e1;
    padding: 2px;
    border: solid 1px #cfcfcf;
    margin: 14px;
}

#main .thumbnail {
    background-image: url('http://images.idealer1.com/getimage/188/4937261.jpg');
    height: 125px;
    width: 188px;
}
```

```html
<div class="thumbBorder">
    <div class="thumbnail"> </div>
</div>
```

What would be the proper way to get the outer `div` `thumbBorder` to wrap tightly around the inner `div` `thumbnail`?

Right now, the outer `div` `thumbBorder` is expanding to the limits of its entire outer content block.

Comment: **Related:** [Tightly wrap multiple child divs with a parent div](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14129683/1497596)

Answer (score 3):

The only way to have a block element shrink to fit its contents is to give it a `float`. If you need that behavior, and also need to center, check out [display: inline-block](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
float: left;
```

or

```
float: right;
```

or also

```
display: inline;
```