# Tightly wrap multiple child divs with a parent div

Tags: html, css

I want to tightly wrap some divs with an outer div, such that the outer div resizes with the addition of more inner divs. Right now, the parent div just fills 100% width, which isn't quite right.

[**Here's some code and a Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LX3jJ/):

```
<div id="toolbar">
    <ul>
        <li><i class="icon-facebook-sign"></i></li>
        <li><i class="icon-twitter-sign"></i></li>
        <li><i class="icon-envelope-alt"></i></li>
        <li><i class="icon-cloud-upload"></i></li>
        <li><i class="icon-cog"></i></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

---

```
#toolbar {
    overflow:hidden;
    padding:5px;
    background:#FFF;
    border-radius:5px;
    border:1px solid #AAA;
    margin-bottom:15px;
}
    #toolbar ul {
        overflow:auto;
        list-style:none;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }
    #toolbar li {
        display:inline;
        padding:5px;
        background:#606c88;
        color:#FFF;
        font-size:24px;
        border-radius:5px;
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fit <div> tightly around enclosed image?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7178537/fit-div-tightly-around-enclosed-image)

Comment: Set `display` of `#toolbar` to `inline-block` solves the problem. http://jsfiddle.net/LX3jJ/3/

Comment: **Related:** [Do divs expand vertically to fit their children divs?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5450371/1497596)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `display`-attribute of the outer div `#toolbar` and the list `#toolbar ul` to `inline-block`:

```
#toolbar {
    overflow:hidden;
    padding:5px;
    background:#FFF;
    border-radius:5px;
    border:1px solid #AAA;
    margin-bottom:15px;
    display:inline-block;
}
#toolbar ul {
    overflow:auto;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

I hope it helps...

**EDIT**: You said "tightly wrap". You have a padding in the toolbar-div. So if you really want to have it with no space towards the outer div, remove the line `padding:5px`.

Answer (score -1):

```
#toolbar {
  float: left;
}
```

This will "shrink wrap" the `.toolbar` around its contents.  You'll need another element after it to `clear: both;` so that you don't get elements to align to the right of the `.toolbar` if you don't want that.

Comment: why a -1 here? Unless there are other parameters not mentioned, `float` does exactly what is being asked. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scrimothy/4hA26/)